# How to tell `git diff <commit>` to diff untracked files that used to be tracked in `<commit>`?

Tags: git, git-diff

If I want to see the differences between `<commit>` and the working directory (WD), I run

```
% git diff <commit>
```

This usually does what I want, but it if the WD contains files that were being tracked at the time that `<commit>` was created, but are not being tracked now (or in the current branch), then the resulting diffs treat these files in the WD as if they were `/dev/null`.

I can imagine situations in which this would be the appropriate behavior, but at the moment I'd like to be able to see the "real" differences between `<commit>` and the current directory, using the list of files that were being tracked at the time that `<commit>` was created.

Is there some way to instruct `git diff` to behave this way?

EDIT: if there were a way to stash away (and later restore) *just* the index, maybe running `git reset <commit>` before `git diff <commit>` would produce a full comparison between `<commit>` and the WD, but I haven't yet figured out how to selectively stash away (and later restore) the index...  Oh!  I guess I could just do a "poor man's stash" like this: `cp -a .git/index .git/index.bak`!?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
git diff --diff-filter=M
```

To show only the modified files and not the deleted ones

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the (newly-"untracked") files to be ignored; I want them to be compared by `git diff` against their counterparts in `<commit>`.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a temporary dummy commit that holds the state of your current working tree, and comparing to that? Something like

```
$ git checkout -b working-tree-state
$ git add -f .
$ git commit -m "The current working tree state"
$ git diff <commit>
```